# using Command and form case error just-in-time (JIT)

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I'm building a new c# form for AutoCAD so I have code where it build a rectangle by polyline and when i use button form to call the class it give me the Error

> Application does not support Windows Forms just-in-time (JIT)

So I solve the problem by using

> acDoc.LockDocument

and it worked but now I have to use this command to fillet my rectangle but even LockDocument doesn't help any idea plz :)

> acDoc.Database.Filletrad = 5.0;

> ed.Command("_.fillet", "Polyline", acPoly.ObjectId);

> Note without using form and calling the code even with out to LockDocument the code work but I still need the form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK5AV.png)

Comment: by using ed.Command i'm getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the way how to call modeless form I was calling the form like this:

```cs
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
```

But basically it should be like this:

```cs
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
Application.ShowModalDialog(null, f1, false);
```